# call function compress with NDK (Android)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like to use the following code from/in the NDK part.

```
OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

I started coding the NDK function like this :

```
void compress(JNIEnv* env, jobject fOut){

  jclass bitmapCompressFormat = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/graphics/Bitmap$CompressFormat");
  jfieldID CFFieldID = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,bitmapCompressFormat, "JPEG","Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$CompressFormat;");
  jobject CFObj = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env,bitmapCompressFormat, CFFieldID);

}
```

But I'm stuck, should I use the CallObjectMethod?

PS: the bitmap is a global variable in the NDK code.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is the last updated version :

```
jobject bitmap_array[10];

void compress(JNIEnv* env, jobject *fOut){

jclass bitmapCompressFormat = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/graphics/Bitmap$CompressFormat");
jfieldID CFFieldID = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,bitmapCompressFormat, "JPEG","Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$CompressFormat;");
jobject CFObj = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env,bitmapCompressFormat, CFFieldID);

jmethodID compressBitmapMethodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,bitmap_array[0],"compress","(Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$CompressFormat;ILjava/io/OutputStream;)Z");

(*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env,bitmap_array[0], compressBitmapMethodID, CFObj, (jint)100, *fOut);

}

--------------------- SDK --------------------------
public native void compress(OutputStream fOut);
...
OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
compress(fOut);
```

I have no error message in the logcat, the activity closes when I call the method "compress".

Thank for your help.